# Getting IndexOutOfBoundsException error while updating RecyclerView

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-recyclerview, adapter

Hi I want to delete row in my database which is being displayed in a Recycler View, While I click the delete button the data is deleted but my recyclerView will not update and my app crashes.

here is my delete method

```
public int deleteNote(int id) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(TABLE_NAME,"id=?",new String[] {String.valueOf(id)});

    }
```

and here is my popop menu in RV Adapter which when i click on delete the row of database is deleted but my app crashes

```
holder.more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(c,holder.more);
                popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.more_menu);
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                        switch (item.getItemId()){

                            case R.id.delete:



                                Note note = notes.get(position);
                                NoteDBAdapter noteDBAdapter = new NoteDBAdapter(c);
                                int result = noteDBAdapter.deleteNote(notes.get(position).getId());
                                if (result > 0){
                                    Toast.makeText(c, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    notes.remove(notes.get(position));
                                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }else {
                                    Toast.makeText(c, "failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }

                            default:
                                return false;
                        }

                    }
                });

                popupMenu.show();
            }
        });
```

i would appreciate any tip...(:

Comment: what is the error?? post your logcat

Answer (score 0):

IndexOutOfBoundsException occurs when you try to select a value from an array that goes beyond its size.

Check the array or any such stuff like from where you are storing data and getting it.